# How do I add the wifi and bluetooth icon to the menubar programatically (from the command line)?

Tags: wifi, command-line, bluetooth, menu-bar, setup

We have a large number of computers to set up and would like to add the wifi and bluetooth icons to the menubar. How can I turn these settings on via a shell script or command line instruction?

Comment: No, that just turns bluetooth on and off - there is another checkbox in the bluetooth GUI to display the icon in the menu bar.

Comment: Ah, ok, I missed that part of your question.  I'll remove the dup.  It would help if you added the script you have so far so we can look and see the error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Wi-Fi one is there by default, but if you want to be sure, you can use

`open '/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu'`

`open '/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/AirPort.menu'`

to add them to the menu bar.

*(Note: those paths are valid from at least El Capitan to Catalina.)*